# What exception is thrown when DirectorySearcher.FindOne() is called and AD is unavailable?

Tags: .net, active-directory

Is there an exception thrown (if so what), null returned, empty data table returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException. The message will be "The server is not operational."